# Is there a variant of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal and/or acceptance function depending on the history?

Tags: distributions, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings

Is there a version of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm where either

1. the proposal kernel; or
2. the acceptance function

might depend on the whole history (or at least a part of it) of the chain so far?

For example, the papers [Adaptive proposal distribution for random walk Metropolis algorithm](https://www.academia.edu/16453972/Adaptive_proposal_distribution_for_random_walk_Metropolis_algorithm) and [On an adaptive version of the Metropolis–
Hastings algorithm with independent
proposal distribution](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4616755) seem to be in this direction, but I wasn't able to find formal verifications.

*EDIT*: For example, what I would like to do is something like the following: Fix $k,h\in\mathbb N$, generate $k$ proposal candidates and choose the one which has the maximimum minimum distance to the last $h$ generated samples.

Another idea would be to introduce a energy function $f$ and favor proposals $y$ such that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_i,y)$ is large, where $x_1,\ldots,x_i$ are the samples generated so far.

Comment: There is a large literature on adaptive MCMC algorithms, as for instance the corpus of theoretical and methodological work produced by Gareth Roberts and Jeff Rosenthal on diminishing adaptation. Jeff has an R package backing these results. See also the tutorial by [Christophe Andrieu and Johannes Thoms](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/sail/readings/andrieu-thoms.pdf).